# Infinitude of smooth shifted primes in arithmetic progression with fixed moduli

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $P(n)$ denote the largest prime factor of $n$. I wanted to know if an analogue of Baker-Harman estimate for smooth shifted primes in arithmetic progressions with fixed moduli is there in literature.

Baker-Harman proved that there exist infinitely many primes $p$ such that $P(p-1)<p^{0.2961}$ and the exponent was recently improved to $0.2844$ by Lichtman [recently](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.09641). Has someone considered the problem of obtaining an inifnitude of such primes which are of form $1\pmod{a}$ for some fixed modulus $a$?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It should be said that the improvement to $0.2844$ is due to Lichtman (https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.09641).

Comment: @ThomasBloom I have edited the post. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only relevant result I found is [a paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-52/issue-3/Smooth-values-of-shifted-primes-in-arithmetic-progressions/10.1307/mmj/1100623415.full) by Banks, Harcharras, and Shparlinski. They did not establish existence of such smooth numbers but instead gave an upper bound.

Let

$$
\pi_h(x,y;q,a)=\#\{p\le x:P(p-h)<y\wedge p\equiv a\pmod q\}.
$$

Then uniformly for $x\ge y\ge2$ and $q\ge1$, they proved that

$$
\pi_h(x,y;q,a)\ll{u\rho(u)\over\varphi(q)}\prod_{\substack{p|h\\p>2}}{p-1\over p-2}\pi(x).
$$

Comment: I had seen this paper before. I would like to point out that in a recent email exchange, I received a confirmation by Lichtman that the approach of Baker-Harman or his can be modified to include the case of fixed modulus.

Comment: I did find [Lichtman's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.09641) during the search while writing the answer. As I did not have communications with him before about such generalizations, I did not put his result in the answer.